# Are there quantum algorithms showing a double exponential advantage?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-advantage

I would like to know if there are known quantum algorithms that provide a double exponential advantage compared to the best known classical algorithms.

More precisely, if the characteristics of the problem to simulate depend on an integer $n$, the quantum computer requires a number of gates polynomial in $n$ while the classical computer requires $\exp(\exp(P(n))$ gates where $P(n)$ is a polynome.

If there doesn't exist such an algorithm, is there some general proof that shows that a double exponential speedup is impossible with quantum computers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Classical computers can simulate quantum computers with an exponential overhead. Thus, there cannot be a doubly exponential speedup (unless maybe in some blackbox setting, cf Deutsch-Jozsa).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fully agree with your first point (I didnt think about that). But then I dont understand your second statement. If we simulate the circuit of deutsch josza the classical computer will have an answer in exponential time. What do you mean about black box setting. Could you elaborate?

Comment: If you don't count the time it takes to run the oracle (as an actual circuit), but count queries to the oracle, the story can be different -- at least in principle. E.g., in DJ & in a setting where you want a deterministic outcome and have deterministic classical computation, you need $2^n/2-1$ queries classically, but only one query quantumly. So the speedup -- in terms of queries to a black-box function -- is "as big as you wish", in some sense. --- I'm pretty sure you can get rid of this even in an oracle setting with suitable conditions, which is why I wrote "maybe".

Comment: I think I see what you mean. But if we can allow some black box for the quantum case (i.e. not decomposing the box in a gateset), couldn't we somehow do the same classically and define some "classical black box" that is called once? Isn't it an "unfair" comparison to do this? What I mean is that the notion of what is in the blackbox seems very subjective and I guess we could do a trick that would also make the classical version "very fast".

Comment: I think discussing about oracles is both beyond the scope of the question and the answer.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch isn't that also exponential?

Comment: @user253751 If $O(n)$ is exponentially faster than $O(2^n)$, then probably $O(1)$ vs $O(2^n)$ is something more than exponentially faster.

Comment: @eugenhu $O(4^n)$ is also exponential and it shouldn't take long to convince yourself that $4^n$ grows faster than $n\cdot 2^n$

Comment: @user253751 ? I'm not sure I understand, I thought the question you were asking Norbert was if Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm didn't count as more than "double exponential". I don't know if "speedup" is a commonly defined thing, but the question seems like it's saying a $O(f(n))$ algorithm vs $O(g(n))$ algorithm has $h$ speedup if $h(f(n))=g(n)$, or something like that.

Comment: @eugenhu but in this case $h(x) = x$. Note that it is big-O notation - only the "biggest" speedup appears inside the brackets - it appears that $O(k^n) = O(n\cdot k^n)$ when k is an unspecified constant (as it is in the term "exponential speedup")

Comment: @user253751 Wait, in the D-J case, $f(n)=1$ for the quantum query complexity and $g(n)=2^n$ for the classical query complexity, there is no $h(x)$ that satisfies $h(f(n))=g(n)$ right? I don't see how it is $h(x)=x$.

Comment: @eugenhu https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: @user253751 Yes.. I didn't mean to start an extended discussion about this, so I'll just leave it at that unless you want to move this to a chat.

Answer (score 2):

There is a super exponential query reduction for a quantum algorithm that solves SEARCH WITH ADVICE problem for a power law advice distribution with average-case query complexity O(1) as N tends to infinity.[Link to paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.10790)